# Sharing a devotion?

Tags: phrases

Someone told me that this phrase is grammatically incorrect, but I do not understand why?

> XYZ is a fellowship of adults sharing a devotion to encourage students.

Comment: Welcome, but I think this question is better suited to our sister site, [English Language Learners.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: oh ok, feel free to transfer it if you deem it better

Comment: You are for sure not the only one using it http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sharing+a+devotion&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share= - I also do not see why it cannot be answered here. In my opinion it is not really an English Learner question since the expression seems to be in general use

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this usage either. I suspect they are implying that you cannot 'share' a personal feeling? Not sure.

Comment: I'd say you need a noun phrase as the object of *to*; something like "devotion to the encouragement of students" or "devotion to encouraging students".

Answer (score 2):

It's not ungrammatical in itself, but there is a subtle shift in meaning if a different verb form is used. The sentence as stated probably doesn't mean what is intended.

Consider

> - XYZ is a fellowship of adults sharing a devotion to encourage students
> - XYZ is a fellowship of adults sharing a devotion to encouraging students

The first indicates that the students are encouraged because the adults share an [unspecified] devotion. The second indicates that the object of the devotion is the students' encouragement.

I suspect that the second sense is what is intended. For that, the verb form is wrong: it needs to be a gerund. A devotion is to a noun of some sort.

Comment: yes the second meaning is the intended one. However, 'adults sharing a devotion to encouraging students' sounds funny to me, should it say something like 'adults sharing a devotion toward encouraging students.' In the last sentence I replaced to with toward. but I am not sure that is the best word to use.

Comment: No, a devotion is **to** a noun of some sort.